# Integral inequality $\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right )^2dx \leq 4\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx$

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration, integral-inequality

> Let $f \in C^1([0;1],\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0)=0$.
>   $$\text{Prove that} \qquad \int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right )^2dx \leq 4\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx$$

**My attempt:**
Let $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{x^\alpha},           & \quad x\neq 0\\ 
\frac{f^{(\alpha)}(0)}{\alpha!}, & \quad x=0
\end{cases},$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g \in C^1([0;1],\mathbb{R})$.
We have
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)&=x^\alpha g(x)\\
f'(x)&=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}g(x)+x^\alpha g'(x)\\
I &= 4\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx \\
  &= 4\left ( \int_{0}^{1}\alpha^2x^{2\alpha-2}(g(x))^2dx
            + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha}(g'(x))^2dx
            + \int_{0}^{1}2g(x)g'(x)\alpha x^{2\alpha-1}dx \right )\\ 
  &=  4\left ( \int_{0}^{1}\alpha^2x^{2\alpha-2}(g(x))^2dx 
             + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha}(g'(x))^2dx
             + \int_{0}^{1}((g(x))^2)'\alpha x^{2\alpha-1}dx \right )\\ 
  &=  4\left ( \int_{0}^{1}\alpha^2x^{2\alpha-2}(g(x))^2dx
             + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha}(g'(x))^2dx
             + \alpha (g(1))^2\\
             - \int_{0}^{1}(g(x))^2\alpha(2\alpha-1)x^{2\alpha-2}dx \right )\\ 
 &  \text{ (integrate by parts)}\\ 
 &= 4\left ( \int_{0}^{1}\alpha(1-\alpha)x^{2\alpha-2}(g(x))^2dx + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha}(g'(x))^2dx + \alpha (g(1))^2 \right )\\ 
 &= 4\left ( \alpha(1-\alpha)\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right )^2dx + \int_{0}^{1}x^{2\alpha}(g'(x))^2dx + \alpha (g(1))^2 \right )\\ 
 &\geq 4\alpha(1-\alpha)\int_{0}^{1}\left ( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right )^2dx
\end{split}
$$
I'm stuck here because $\alpha(1-\alpha) \leq 0$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.
Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's $α$ for??

Comment: If $f(x)=xg(x)$ then $$4\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx = 4\left ( \int_{0}^{1}x^2(g'(x))^2dx + (g(1))^2\right )$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this instead: assume $f$ is not identcally zero, and let $0 < \epsilon < 1$ be sufficiently small that $\displaystyle \int_\epsilon^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx > 0.$  Integrate by parts to make the estimate
$$ \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx = \frac{f(\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} - \frac{f(1)^2}{1} + \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1x 2 f(x) f'(x) \, dx \le \frac{f(\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} + \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1x 2 f(x) f'(x) \, dx.$$

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives you
$$ \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1x 2 f(x) f'(x) \, dx \le 2 \left( \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\epsilon}^1 f'(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}$$ so you can divide to obtain
$$\left(  \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \le \left(  \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{-1/2} \frac{f(\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} + 2\left( \int_{\epsilon}^1 f'(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$

There are two things to note: the expression 
$\displaystyle \left(  \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{-1/2}$ is decreasing as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, and 
$\displaystyle \frac{f(\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} \le \int_0^\epsilon f'(t)^2 \, dt \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.
Thus 
$$ \left(  \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{-1/2} \frac{f(\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon}  \to 0$$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Take the limit in all three terms above to find
$$ \left( \int_0^1 \frac 1{x^2} f(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2} \le 2 \left( \int_0^1 f'(x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$